# How to modify Accounts.createUser in Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am new in meteor and working with existing mongodb. When I execute `Accounts.createUser` in meteor it creates user in mongodb. The default user creation structure is.

```
{
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-04-28T06:25:24.584Z"),
    "services" : {
        "google" : {
            "accessToken" : "...",
            "idToken" : "eyJh...",
            "expiresAt" : 1430205913568,
            "email" : "zxy@abc.com",
            "verified_email" : true,
            "name" : "ABC XYZ",
            "given_name" : "ABC",
            "family_name" : "XYZ",
            "picture" : "photo.jpg",
            "locale" : "en"
        },
        "resume" : {
            "loginTokens" : [ 
                {
                    "when" : ISODate("2015-04-28T06:25:24.618Z"),
                    "hashedToken" : "QWTfTNUEcZwb4OvU"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to modify the structure like.

```
{
    "email" : "zxy@abc.com",
    "password" : "xyz",
    "loginType": "google",
    "country" : "US",
    "state" : "California",
    "profile_image" : "photo.jpg",
    "fullname" : "ABC XYZ",
    "status" : "active",
    "timestamp" : NumberLong(1420780653),
}
```

How or where should I modify the default user creation structure?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [onCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser):

```
//server code
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  //here you can modify user
  if (options.profile)
    user.profile = options.profile;
  return user;
});
```

But be careful, if you remove *services* field, user will probably not be able to log in with external services.

Comment: Thanks,How can I change `users` collection name to `appUser` ?

Comment: Meteor.users is collection with name `users`. I don't think you can change name of the collection because Meteor simply works with name `users`.